# Trying to understand how git --graph works and showing branches

Tags: git

I've been using Git for a while, but more casually just merging in topic branches and pull requests. I'm not understanding what `git log --oneline --graph` is telling me here. The two branches shown are master and my6.

[image]

Specifically, I don't understand the `4e4e1fd jt2 on master` commit which seems like it's on the wrong branch. Is the star on the left branch showing what branch it's in?

To get here, I:

1. edited file and commit 'jt on master' on master branch
2. created and checkout outmy6 branch
3. made edits and commit as '#1 on my6'
4. checked out master
5. made edits and commit as 'jt2 on master'
6. merged my6 branch onto master; should be a 3 way merge

The graph is obviously correct but it seems like `4e4e1fd jt2 on master` is on the wrong branch, appearing on the my6 branch rather than master. What am I not understanding?

Comment: The star indeed shows on which branch the commit was made. So the `jt2 on master` is correctly displayed on the master branch in the graph-representation

Comment: thx for clarifying @pyerwin - probably just a limitation of terminal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the right branch.  Here's how we know:

> 4. **checked out master**
> 5. made edits and commited as 'jt2 on master'

You checked out your master branch, then made the changes on it directly.  You then went back to your other branch and made *other* changes.  This is why you don't see the change on `my6`; there's nothing yet linking their ancestry chain together.

When you merge `my6` into `master`, both commits appear as they should, and there really shouldn't be any three-way merges unless it was the same file.

If you want to audit this, you can check `git reflog`, which will give you a synopsis of every action you've taken in Git so far, up to about 3 months.  You'll be able to see which branch you were on when you commited and merged.

If you want to *improve* the layout you get from the terminal, then you can use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`, which will give you more context into the branches and what is on them.

Comment: thx, makato - I think I was just confused as to the visual representation. It looks like that commit is somehow part of the other branch but that's just a limitation of a terminal output (I think).